# JSON structure representation

Tags: objective-c, json

I would like to use JSON in my application, i have not never use it. i have an object like this :

```
@interface Selection : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * book_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * contenu;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * page_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * nbrOfOccurences;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * next;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * previous;
```

@end

I would like to construct the `JSON` to synchronize to my server. What is the structure to use of my objects `"Selection"`, i.e. : How to represent many objects of `"Selection"` in `JSON` format ? thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:book_id, 
                                             contenu,
                                             page_id,
                                             nbrOfOccurences,
                                             next,
                                             previous,
                                             nil];
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *jsonData = [JSONSerializer dataWithJSONObject:objects
                                              options:0
                                                error:&error];
```

Now `jsonData` contains a JSON-encoded representation of the `objects` array. To get them back, reverse the process:

```
NSArray *objects = [JSONSerializer JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                              options:0
                                              error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0):

Put them into an Array, and then serialize the Array using a JSON serializer.

Here's the one I use:

https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit